# Can we call a Webservice from an ASP.NET MVC 3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

Before, I've published a web service on my host and it's used for my ASP.NET 1.0 web application. 
And now, I want to upgrade my web app into an ASP.NET MVC 3 (or 4) project, can or should I re-use my exist web service?

Thanks in advance for any ideas and suggestions!

Comment: yes, reuse the web service, and in MVC 3/4 poject just add this web service as a service reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse existing web services. No problem at all. Just add a service reference and consume it from your MVC application. For example you could have an implementation of your repository which instead of hitting a database will instantiate the web service proxy and hit the web service to fetch the data.

Comment: @Dimitrov we recently had a bad experience with ASP.Net gridview based web app and currently in the lookout for technologies within MS platform. I see that ASP.NET MVC pretty great when creating a native application where database is auto generated. But usually that's not the case. The databases are already in place with users' current application repositories. So we are required to consume existing databases as well as couple of web services from a third-party software (ERP).

Comment: The web app must be resposive to access over pc and mobile  and operated on a multi user environment for number of CRUD operations. Certain multiple CRUD operations must be done within one page without popping or opening up new pages.e.g. how classic gridviews did on one page. So what and where can we start to explore MVC framework for our requirement? Sort of like a recommended direction for us to start over.